# How to set a domain name instead of a IP address?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I am new using ubuntu, so take that in mind :)

I have a project at the school in wich I have to create an Intranet using a switch and router. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and apache2 server.

I have already create a webpage in HTML and I can connect different computers in order to enter to the page.
But the only way that I can enter is by typing the ip address. I am trying to enter to the page but by using a domain name like "www.example.com" not just numbers.

I followed the steps to create the intranet here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts
By the way, I already have the domain (I got it here www.noip.com)

Thank you >:)

Comment: You will have to setup DNS.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, www.noip.com is a dynamic DNS provider. What this boils down to is that it allows hosts with dynamic (DHCP) IP addresses to run a small client program that updates the noip database with the current IP address of the host where the client is running. Note that this will also typically require that the IP address of your server is routable over the internet or that portmapping/static NAT is established to such an address.

However, if you are not running the client software, there is nothing that will update the database, thus the hostname will not be resolvable. Or if your IP address is not visible on the internet, your server won't be reachable.

What you can do under these circumstances is:

- either configure a local DNS server and configure your clients to use it as a DNS source
- or you can enter your server's FQDN in /etc/hosts of all of your clients which would allow them to resolve the name to IP address. Obviously, this will work only if you have a known set of clients.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you have to setup domain name resolution. You might already have it working without knowing. Please check:

- Can you ping the server by it's hostname (e.g. `ping example-host`)? The hostname can be found easily in Ubuntu. It's the part of the prompt between the @ and the :. You should also try the same with suffixing `.local` → `ping example-host.local`.
- Does you router provide a DNS service. Some router do and they will allow you to resolve the host in a special domain.

If both don't work you still have some options:

- setup your own DNS server and configure all the client to use it.
- Manually configure the hostname in the hosts file of the clients; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)
- Use a domain you have control and create a new A (or for IPv6 AAAA) record in it. The IP in the record can be local only if does not matter. People from the outside would be able to resolve the hostname to the IP, but they would not be able to access the server.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to your external IP address assigned by your ISP.

If you already have a domain at no ip you simply need to configure dynamic DNS in your router/firewall and forward the necessary ports (80 & 443) for your web server to the internal IP address of your web server.

Typically to log into your firewall you look for the default gateway address that is assigned to your web server and log in by typing the address into a browser on a system that is connected to the network.

Edit: the other way to get an IP address to appear as a domain address is to set up a virtual host in your web server that resolves to that domain name and edit the hosts file of all of your LAN computers to resolve that domain at your web servers internal IP address. I have more info on that if you want.